# Object is "not callable" after adding __call__ method to instance

Tags: python, inheritance, callable

I have the following code

```
import numpy as np

class Estimator(object):
    name = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.__call__ = self._call

class Mean(Estimator):
    name = 'mean'

    def _call(self, data):
        return np.mean(data)

data = np.arange(10)
```

now, why I can't use the second class as a functor as the first?

It seems to work:

```
M = Mean()
print M.__call__(data)  # -> 4.5
```

M has the method `__call__`:

```
print '__call__' in dir(M)  # -> True
```

but it doesn't work

```
print M(data)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'Mean' object is not callable
```

Comment: Special methods are looked up in class not instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Ashwini says, "Special methods are looked up in class not instances".

So the following would work as you expect (although I can't imagine why you would want to):

```
class Estimator(object):
    name = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.__call__ = self.__class__._call

class Mean(Estimator):
    name = 'mean'

    def _call(self, data):
        return np.mean(data)
```

Comment: Setting the `__call__` method class-wide to the new instance's `_call` means multiple estimators of the same class won't work right.

Comment: @user2357112 explain that... in the given example, it's setting `Mean.__call__` to `Mean._call`. What's it got to do with the instance?

Comment: No, it's setting `Mean.__call__` to `self._call`, a bound method.

Comment: @user2357112 ok, I see your point... updated to act upon the class.

Comment: @isedev: I need it because I want to resolve which function to call with `__call__` when building the class. In my real code I have two `_call` functions and the base class decides which to use depending on an argument of `__init__`